# docker compose documentation tutorial, Unknown database 'todos'

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

i followed docker compose tutorial
https://docs.docker.com/get-started/08_using_compose/
to create composer file for todo app with mysql service

- i did the same docker compose as the tutorial
  but it gave me this error

```
app-mysql-1  | 2022-05-28T21:55:26.950553Z 3 [Note] Unknown database 'todos'
app-app-1    | Error: ER_BAD_DB_ERROR: Unknown database 'todos'
```

- i executed mysql container services to see if todos database created or not

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

docker compose

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  app:
    image: node:12-alpine
    command: sh -c "yarn install && yarn run dev"
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: mysql
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DB: todos

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - todo-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: todos

volumes:
  todo-mysql-data:
```

Comment: What are the two PNG images you've included in the question?  You say "it gave me this error"; can you [edit] the question to include the text of the error message, and not a screen shot?

Comment: Your apo starts before the db is ready

Comment: @DavidMaze i edited the post, sorry

Comment: @kofemann i tried depends_on properties to made mysql service run first before app service but unfortunately error still there

Answer (score 1):

Running just the mysql portion of your docker-compose file seems to have worked for me.

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - todo-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: todos

volumes:
  todo-mysql-data
```

[image]

You might want to try deleting the volume and recreating your containers.

`docker volume rm todo-mysql-data`
`docker-compose up --force-recreate`

Comment: your answer made me to see volume lists and i found that there was a volume with the same name that i tried to created [todo-mysql-data] so when i wrote docker compose up it tried to create volume with the same name but because name was already exist it append it like this  [app_todo-mysql-data] so things got wrong

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Hambrook i found that there was a volume with the same name i tried to create

```
docker volume ls 
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
local     app_todo-mysql-data
local     todo-mysql-data
```

so i removed it and write command again

```
 docker compose up
```

and it's work